# Сервлеты java. Выбор DAO в рантайме

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, dao

Есть web приложение. При входе попадаем на страницу логина, логику самого приложения опустим.

В качестве источника данных о зарегистрированных пользователях испольуем шаблон Data Access Object, а именно интерфейс IUserDao, который имеет 2 имплементации: DatabaseUserDao и допустим MemoryUserDao.

Для получения экземпляра используем фабрику UserFactory с методом getClassFromFactory() который возвращает IUserDao.

Каким образом возможно реализовать сервлет, в частности метод init() чтобы получить возможность определить какую именно имплементацию IUserDao использовать?
Идея в том, чтобы избежать в коде инициализации конкретной имплементацией:

```
IUserDao userDao = new DatabaseUserDao();
```

*Вот так не хорошо*

Спасибо!

Comment: 1. сделайте разные сервлеты для разных типов. 2. Используйте Spring

Comment: делать разные сервлеты это еще хуже. Вроде бы можно и без спринга обойтись, пытаюсь разобраться через config.getInitParameter()

Comment: Вы в курсе что метод `init` у сервлета срабатывает один раз и все?

Comment: А чем это мне мешает? При старте контейнера будет определен в `init` источник данных

Comment: Вам в любом случае где-то явно придётся указать класс. Можно в сервлет записать `Class<? extends IUserDao> clazz = DatabaseUserDao.class;`, а потом делать `clazz.newInstance();` ну или отдавать как аргумент фабрики `Factory.getInstance(clazz);`

Comment: Зачем плодить море классов для таких вещей, когда можно сделать 1 с разыми методами или если на то пошло конструкторами.

Comment: @And Вы про имплементации DAO? Если я вас правильно понял, тогда зачем вообще много разных объектов, можно ведь все поля и методы в один положить и дергать по необходимости

Comment: Нет, имплементация тут не нужна - она используется для расширения и повторного использования, тут необходимо построить логику на методах или конструкторах, без раздувания кода.

Comment: @And Допустим, у меня может быть 3 разных источника данных - xml file, jdbc, RAM. Задачи, которые они выполняют - добавление add() и проверка наличия пользователя get(). Внутри они будут абсолютно по-разному реализованы. Для этого и нужен интерфейс и имплементации, чтобы за общим интерфейсом объекта, в данном случае IUserDao скрыть конкретную реализацию и однообразно проводить операции добавления и получения. В противном случае отделить слой источника данных от контроллера не получится.

Comment: 3 конструктора хватит за глаза.

Comment: При помощи конструктора переписать абсолютно не подобные тела методов, первый из которых работает с xml, второй работает с мапой, третий с базой данных? Сомнительное качество кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это все делается через паттерн Strategy. Вы определяете множество разных реализаций, после их всех ложите в контейнер по ключу. В нужном месте достоете нужную DAO и все.

Пример:

```
public interface Dao {

    void execute();

}

public class DatabaseDao implements Dao {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Database");
    }

}

public class MemoryDao implements Dao {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Memory");
    }

}

public class Container {

    private Map<String, Dao> container;

    public Container() {
        container = new HashMap<>();
        container.put("database", new DatabaseDao());
        container.put("memory", new MemoryDao());
    }

    public Dao getDao(String key) {
        return container.get(key);
    }

}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.getDao("memory").execute();
        container.getDao("database").execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ну или если вы не хотите создавать объект, то возвращайте фабрики для этих DAO и делайте ленивую инициализацию.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, правильно ли я понял вашу задачу, но опишу как делал я.
В файле `db.properties` задал `factory.class=model.dao.jdbc.JdbcDaoFactory`
В классе `DaoFactory` у меня есть переменная `private static DaoFactory instance;` и метод, который в эту переменную пишет вам экземпляр созданной фабрики. У меня это `public static DaoFactory getInstance()`. Он инициализирует переменную `instance = (DaoFactory) Class.forName(factoryClass).newInstance();` Переменная `String factoryClass = dbProps.getProperty("factory.class");`. Соответственно, меняя `.properties`-файл, вы подставляете нужную вам фабрику.

Comment: Спасибо! Пока в процессе реализации схожего по задумке решения: в web.xml в content-param храним userSource. По имени через config.getInitParameter(String userSource) получаем значение, которое будет ключом в мапе. Чтобы избавиться от явного приведения типа используем вышеописанный by Andrii Torzhkov контейнер. Дальше еще разбираюсь в направлении Listener'a, задача которого будет заполнение мапы значениями.